# JuliaLang plot with large xtick label numbers is displayed with too many figures in scientific notation and malformed exponent

Tags: julia, axis-labels, scientific-notation, plots.jl

I am using `Plots.jl` with the default GR() plotting backend rather than pyplot from `JuliaLang`. The x-axis tick numbers are in the thousands and the series plot produced uses scientific notation [wiki examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) to display these numbers on the x-axis. Too many decimal points are given which is understandable since the axis point chosen is set by the program, but even for `1.00000x10` these trailing zeros are printed. Below is an example and a mistake in the exponentiation is produced. How can this be fixed. The fontfamily was even changed to see if the effect is removed but it remains. (`xticks=1:step:final`)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `xformatter` to change the format of the ticks ([source](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/1595#issue-338597443)):

```
using Plots
let n_samples = 80,
    d = Plots.fakedata(n_samples,1),
    i = collect(1:n_samples) .* 1e10
    plot(i,d, 
         xformatter = x->string(Int(x/1e10),"*pow10"))
end
```

This doesn't seem to be in the docs.